# Problems with nsstring from file local

Tags: xcode, file, path, nsstring

I am making an iphone app and I want to be able to load high scores from text files. I made a file called highscores1.txt and added it to my xcode project. When I try to make an NSString from the text in the file, the NSString's value is nil. Here is my code:

```
    NSString *highscore1 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"highscore1.txt" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

I tried changing the file path to its complete path like this:

```
    NSString *highscore1 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/deepikama/Documents/games/Dodge Cars/Dodge Cars/highscore1.txt" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

And this results in the value that I was intending to find. Why does the complete path work but not the local path? How can I make the local path work as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to get it locally. I changed my code to this:

```
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"highscore1" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *highscore1 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think this explains what you need:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Directories_on_iOS_4_(iPhone)#Identifying_the_Documents_Directory

Also, I'm betting that what worked for you was only run on the simulator, and not on an actual device (where the directory structure is different).

Comment: Thats great but can I get it from a local path? That way I could test in the simulator and on a device.

Comment: The simulator also has a Documents directory, corresponding to what you'd find on the device.  Here's a link explaining it: http://idevhub.com/where-is-the-iphone-simulator-filesystem-stored/

Answer (score 0):

When you added that file to your project in XCode, did you select Copy items into destination group's folder

Comment: Yes the text file is in the group folder.